# VMware Player wont install on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, vmware

I have followed these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
chmod +x ./Downloads/VMware-Player*.bundle
gksudo bash ./Downloads/VMware-Player*.bundle
```

I got this output:

> Extracting VMware Installer...done. You must accept the VMware OVF
>   Tool component for Linux End User License Agreement to continue. 
>   Press Enter to proceed.
>
> [######################################################################] 100%

Thats it - nothing else happened. So I then tried:

```
cd Downloads
sudo ./VMware-Player-*.bundle
```

and

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Player-*.bundle
```

and this was the output:

> Extracting VMware Installer...done. You must accept the VMware OVF
>   Tool component for Linux End User License Agreement to continue. 
>   Press Enter to proceed. VMWARE OPEN VIRTUALIZATION FORMAT TOOL LICENSE
>   AGREEMENT
>
> Notice to User: This Open Virtualization Format Tool ("OVF Tool")
>   License Agreement is a CONTRACT between you (either an individual or a
>   single entity) and VMware, Inc. ("VMware"), which covers your use of
>   the VMware software that accompanies this OVF Tool License Agreement
>   and related software components, which may include associated media,
>   printed materials, and "online" or electronic documentation. All such
>   software and materials are referred to herein as the "Software." If
>   you do not agree to the terms of this OVF Tool License Agreement, then
>   do not install or use the Software. By explicitly accepting this OVF
>   Tool License Agreement, however, or by installing, copying,
>   downloading, accessing, or otherwise using the Software, you are
>   acknowledging and agreeing to be bound by the following terms.
>   1. DEFINITIONS.

An endless scroll of text (I tried to get to end holding the return button for 5 mins)
Can someone please help? (Really wish there was a deb package for this very popular software.)

Answer (score 4):

You have to get to the end of that text (the agreement) in order to continue. However, don't hold down the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, because I believe that only goes one line at a time. Instead, if you want to get to the end of the text faster, **hold down the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar**.

*Disclaimer: I'm not telling you to not read the agreement, I'm only informing you on how to progress through the scrolling faster.*

Comment: thanks - that worked as the return key seemed to 'loop' the txt

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark my answer as your accepted answer.

Comment: With one reputation I think the OP has a time limit before he can accept an answer.